# Codeigniter framework: How do we trace where the variables in a given 'view' php code snippet are coming from?

Tags: codeigniter, variables, view, controller, field

I am in a codeigniter project, examining a file in the views folder. The php is as follows:
As a complete beginner, trying to make sense of this, I am trying to change the value of 'username' below to the 'firstname' that is a different field in the database. Changing the field below, from username, to firstname, causes an error.

I notice there is a loop using the variable: $results as $result)

What I want to know -as a lay person - is how to trace back where these variables are being 'called'from and which files to look into in order to find out how to use the required field, in this case, firstname, which is also from the database.

I have looked into the controllers, but can find nothing resembling this and don't know where to start, as the developer hasn't necessarily labelled everything logically.

My question is: As someone coming into a codebase that they don't know, how do you go about tracing back the logic to find out where you need to look to change a variable and make a change.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <?php
                            $rank = 0;
                                foreach($results as $result){$rank++;
                            ?>
                             <tr style="border: 1px solid #ebebeb;padding-bottom: 0px;background-color: #fff;">

                                <td ><?php echo $rank; ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $result->username; ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $result->marks; ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $result->percentage; ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $result->duration; ?></td>
                                <td ><?php echo $result->date_time; ?></td>

                                <td>
                               <?php /*<a href="<?php echo site_url('result/edit/'.$result->id); ?>"><i class="glyph-icon tooltip-button demo-icon icon-edit" title="Edit" style="color:blue;" data-original-title=".icon-edit"></i></a>
                                &nbsp; */?>
                                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure to Delete this Result???');" href="<?php echo site_url('result/delete/'.$result->id); ?>"><i class="glyph-icon tooltip-button demo-icon icon-close" title="Delete" data-original-title=".icon-close" style="color:red;"></i></a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  <?php  } ?>
```

The starting code on the page I mention is below: Again, notice $results. What is it? Where do I identify its origin and seek to find the fields that populate it?

```
    <?php if(empty($results)) {?>

    <div id="page-title">
    <h2>No Results Found.</h2>

     </br>

</div>

    <?php } else { ?>

     <div id="page-title">
    <h2>All Results</h2>
    <h3>Quiz : <?php echo $results[0]->quiz_name; ?></h3>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('result/delAll'); ?>/<?php echo $results[0]->quiz_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="" style="float: right;" id="btnDelete">Delete All</a>
     </br>

</div>
```

What I have done so far:

1. I have found the controller that seems to be relating to it - pasted below:

   > > load->model('results');
   > >             if(!$this->session->userdata('ID'))
   > >             {
   > >                 $this->session->set_flashdata('noAccess', 'Sorry');
   > >                 redirect(site_url());
   > >         }

   ```
   }


   public function index($id='')
   {
       $data['results'] = $this->results->get_resultByQuiz(-1);
       $this->load->view('template/header.php');
       $this->load->view('result/index.php',$data);
       $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
   }

   public function view($id='')
   {
       $data['results'] = $this->results->get_resultByQuiz($id);
       $this->load->view('template/header.php');
       $this->load->view('result/index.php',$data);
       $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
   }

   public function delAll($id = '')
   {

       $updated = $this->results->delAll($id);
       if($updated)
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('resultDeleteSuccess','result');
       }
       else
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('resultDeleteFail','result');
       }
       redirect('quiz');
   }

   public function delete($id = '')
   {

       $updated = $this->results->delete_results($id);
       if($updated)
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('deleteSuccess','result');
       }
       else
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('deleteSuccess','result');
       }
       redirect('result');
   }
   ```

   }

I have also found this related model.

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ("No direct script access allowed");
class Results extends CI_Model {


    public function get_all_results()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('quiz_takers');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get_resultByQuiz($ID)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("select (select quiz_name from quizes where id = qt.quiz_id) as quiz_name, qt.* from quiz_takers qt where qt.quiz_id = '$ID' order by qt.percentage desc  ");
    return $query->result();

        $this->db->where('quiz_id',$ID);
        $query = $this->db->get('quiz_takers');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function delAll($ID = '')
    {
        $this->db->where('quiz_id',$ID);
        return $this->db->delete('quiz_takers',$data);
    }

    public function delete_results($ID = '')
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$ID);
        return $this->db->delete('quiz_takers',$data);
    }
}
```

I am still none the wiser in determining where to alter what is held in that $results variable, so that I can change the field from username to firstname.

I suspect it may have something to do with this:

```
return $query->result();
```

but where do I search for queries? In models/controllers - or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

In `codeigniter`,

- `view` is where you write the code to be seen on front-end.
- `model` is where you write your `DB` queries.
- `controller` is where you connect your `view` and `model`(front-end
  with DB) ie it works as an intermediate. Also, the `routes` are
  generated as your controller-name and then your function-name plus any additional `parameter` you provided to that `function`.

So, if your `route(URL)` is

> **`your-website/controller_name/function_name/additional-parameter`**

you need to look at the `function {function_name}` in your `controller {Controller_name}`.  
 Sometimes you might see that the `controller` or the `function` is not present in the location as it should(from the `URL`) then you need to check if any `route` is provided for that particular `URL` which will be available at **`application->config->routes.php`**

Say if your `URL` is

> **`www.site/xyz`**

```
$route['xyz'] = 'controller_name/function_name'; // route set in routes.php
```

You need to look for `function {function_name}` in your `controller {Controller_name}`.
You need not worry about the `model` or `view` as they're called and loaded in the `controller` itself.
Now, about `$results`,
it is the `key` provided to the `array variable` in the `controller` which acts as `variable` in the `view`. See example -

**Controller**

```
$data['xyz'] = 'some-value'; // or $whatever['xyz'];
$data['abc'] = 'any-value'; // ...

$this->load->view('some_folder/some_view', $data); // pass $data array or $whatever
```

**View** (located at `view->some_folder->some_view.php`)

```
echo $xyz; // output: some-value -- key {xyz} of $data becomes a variable
echo $abc; // output: any-value  -- key {abc} of $data becomes a variable
```

For more details, you might wanna look [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/appflow.html), [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html) and [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html).
See if it helps you.